# Remote programming of spartan-6 FPGAs using ethernet in microblaze

Tags: vhdl, fpga, microblaze

Field upgrade-ability is one of the key features of recent FPGA based systems. I would like to do remote FPGA reconfiguration through an Ethernet port. But i did not find any clues regarding this. 
Can someone shed any additional light on this ?

Thanks!

Comment: 1/ "Can someone shed any additional light on this ?" is **not** a valid question as per the rules of SE. 2/ You need to provide a lot more information then this. 3/ You might need to move to the electrical engineer site but beware that as it stands here the question will be shot down in flames.

Comment: People voted close because of this question being unclear. I don't find it unclear. It's just way to broad. There is no standard solution for this, you need to implement everything yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I use the cores from [FPGA-Cores.com](http://www.fpga-cores.com) for remote update over Ethernet. It works very good in the project I have been involved in. I have used this for both Spartan 6 and Artix devices.
However it is not using Microblaze. The cores are free to download and use if it is not for commercial use.

Comment: Firstly, i have implemented ethernet (lwip RAW_API) using microblaze.I have used the FPGA programmer you have mentioned but it is not detecting the FPGA.Is it because of  lwip ethernet implemented using microblaze?. Is there any other methods to do remote configuration?

Comment: You can not use the programmer without including one of the cores that supports remote programming. So the programmer can't detect any devices.